# Removing items from list in an async function

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, runtime, race-condition

I'm writing a function to remove all subscriptions by keeping a list of the subscription IDs in a List.

I was having issues with

```
     foreach (var subscriptionId in _listOfSubscriptionIds)
     {
           await _hubProxy.Invoke("removeSubscription", subscriptionId);
           _listOfSubscriptionIds.Remove(subscriptionId);
     }
```

because modifying the list in a foreach loop was throwing errors. I found out on this community that I could do `foreach(var subscriptions in _listOfSubscriptionIds.ToList())` but that sounded bad in terms of space complexity, especially if there were around 10000000 subscriptions.

So I changed it to the following:

```
    public async Task RemoveSubscription (string subscriptionId)
    {
        await _hubProxy.Invoke("removeSubscription", subscriptionId);
        _listOfSubscriptionIds.Remove(subscriptionId);
    }
    public void RemoveAllSubscriptions()
    {
        _listOfSubscriptionIds.ForEach(async subscriptionId => await RemoveSubscription(subscriptionId));
    }
```

Some questions:

1. I think the second one is better in terms of space and time complexity, but am I right?
2. Is there is a possible race-condition in the second case that I may be missing?
3. Within RemoveSubscription, is `_listOfSubscriptionIds.Remove(subscriptionId)` also waited upon because it is in an async function...?

Edit: A detail that I didn't share that makes calling `_listOfSubscriptionIds.Clear()` or iterating through the `_listOfSubscriptionIds` problematic is that there may be multiple clients on the `_hubProxy`, each with their unique set of subscriptions.

client 1 with subscriptionIds {a, b, c, d, e}

client 2 with subIds {f, g, h, I, j, k}

client 3 with subIds, {l, m, n, o, p}, etc.

which means when I call client1.RemoveAllSubscriptions(), it may wipe out client2, client3, etc.'s subscriptionIds as well.

Comment: Would it make sense to make your async call to _hubProxy.Invoke for all items in the list, and then do a _listOfSubscriptionIds.Clear() call after that loop ends?

Comment: A detail that I didn't share that makes calling _listOfSubscriptionIds.Clear() problematic is that there may be multiple clients on the _hubProxy, each with their unique set of subscriptions (client 1 with subscriptionIds {a, b, c, d, e}, client 2 with subIds {f, g, h, I, j, k}, client 3 with subIds, {l, m, n, o, p}, etc.) which means when I call client1.RemoveAllSubscriptions(), it may wipe out client2, client3, etc.'s subscriptionIds as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `ForEach` is essentially fire-and-forget; it does not ensure all tasks run to completion.

You may be better to use a for loop in reverse, and keep the tasks so they can be awaited:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = _listOfSubscriptionIds.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    tasks.Add(RemoveSubscription(_listOfSubscriptionIds[i]));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Iterating in reverse ensures that the values at specific indices do not change during the loop.

Comment: But isn't the `async, await` portion of the lambda function within the ForEach statement guaranteeing that the task will run to completion?

Comment: @unixcorn No, the async lambda is generating a task ar each iteration, but nothing is awaiting them.